# How to change CSS when it's ng-disabled?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this `button`:

```
<input type="submit" value="@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT")"
     class="btn-block secondary-button save-changes padding-8"
     ng-disabled="PayoutEnabled==false" ng-click="PayOut()" />
```

But even when it's disabled it has the same `class` as it's enabled, just not clickable. I want to change background when it's disabled so that user can see that button, is disabled. How can I do that? Do I need some `ng-disabled` CSS class or there is some other way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<input type="submit" value="@Translator.Translate("PAYOUT")" class="btn-block 
secondary-button save-changes padding-8" ng-disabled="PayoutEnabled==false" 
ng-click="PayOut()" ng-class="{'diabled-class': !PayoutEnabled}" />
```

this will add css class `diabled-class` to the input when `PayoutEnabled` is `false` (!PayoutEnabled is true).

Answer (score 48):

What **Toress** answered should work fine but you don't need the help of AngularJS here at all (a native implementation & usage is always best).

You can make use of CSS3 since you already have a class on it. Example:

```css
input.save-changes {
    /* some style when the element is active */
}

input.save-changes[disabled] {
    /* styles when the element is disabled */
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

**Edit:** You can immediately test it on this page of StackOverflow. Just inspect the blue button element and put the `disabled` attribute and see it's CSS.

```css
.save-changes {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.save-changes[disabled] {
  background-color: #FF85A1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="PayoutEnabled = true">
  <a href="#" ng-click="PayoutEnabled = !PayoutEnabled">
  {{PayoutEnabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable'}} the below button</a>
  <br>
  <br>

  <input class="save-changes" type="submit" value="PAYOUT" ng-disabled="PayoutEnabled == false" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer that work for me.  I placed ng-disabled="disabled" into my html and i.fa-refresh[disabled] { color: #ccc; } into my CSS

Comment: Glad this helped you!!

Comment: confirmed. first solution did not work for me. this did

Answer (score 10):

AngularJS adds pseudo-class **disabled** when **ng-disabled** is **false** so i think here is the simplest solution to refer to disabled button :

```
button:disabled {
    color:#717782;
}
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.

Comment: Correct, just worth to mention it won't work for IE8 and lower, many people still use those.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. IMHO in 2018 we can skip IE8 support. But using :disabled over [disabled] ? What solution is cleaner and why?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using `Bootstrap` and a more recent `Angular` version than `AngularJs` you can ovverride the default style adding this to the `styles.css` file

```
.btn.disabled, .btn:disabled {
    opacity: .35 !important;
    background-color: gray !important;
}
```

The higher the opacity the darker or more solid the color will be.