# How do I reload md-icon in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, icons

I've got some colorful `md-icon` and wanna change it to a grayscale one (replace with a different grayscale basically) when it's disabled (and in reverse).

I can definitely use .css to see whether a button's disabled: `button[disabled]:hover`, but I'm struggling to see how to combine it together with angular directives (I found a similar demo which works on click: https://codepen.io/elishaterada/pen/mDCEl).

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change CSS when it's ng-disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206104/how-to-change-css-when-its-ng-disabled)

Comment: @Zysce well, so I still have to create a boolean isDisabled variable on the controller itself?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, check the second answer on the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206226/2225619 Otherwise, please [edit] your question, maybe include an example and specify what exactly you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

¿wich file you use for the md-icon, svg or another img file?

you can use ng-style,
if is SVG you do delete 'fill' inside xml svg,and play with the css propertys
but if you need change the color to div o another the next example work perfect!

https://codepen.io/Gibrain/pen/pOdpdW

i hope hel you

```
enter code here
```